# Replace existing chart control with new dynamically created chart control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I have a Windows Form with a chart control.  In my code, I generate a new chart control dynamically.  I need to replace the existing chart control (chartCC) with the new chart control (chart).  i have tried two ways of doing it:

**Method 1**

```
   Chart chart = Charts.CreateNewChart(chartCC.Location.X, chartCC.Location.Y, chartCC.Width, chartCC.Height, dataIdx, 16, 12, 5f, 5f, "BB");

    chartCC = chart;
```

Method 1 does not work.  Nothing happens to the chart control visually.

**Method 2**

```
   Chart chart = Charts.CreateNewChart(chartCC.Location.X, chartCC.Location.Y, chartCC.Width, chartCC.Height, dataIdx, 16, 12, 5f, 5f, "BB");

    chartCC.ChartAreas.Clear();
    foreach (var ca in chart.ChartAreas)
    {
        chartCC.ChartAreas.Add(ca);
    }

    //Chart Series
    chartCC.Series.Clear();
    foreach(var cs in chart.Series)
    {
        chartCC.Series.Add(cs);
    }

    //Chart Titles
    chartCC.Titles.Clear();
    foreach (var title in chart.Titles)
    {
        chartCC.Titles.Add(title);
    }

    //Chart Annotations
    chartCC.Annotations.Clear();
    foreach (var annotation in chart.Annotations)
    {
        chartCC.Annotations.Add(annotation);
    }

        chartCC.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
        chartCC.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chartCC.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;

        chartCC.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chartCC.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chartCC.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

        chartCC.Invalidate();
```

Method 2 works, however it causes a big problem for me.  I have a CursorPositionChanged event handler in my code.

```
private void chartCC_CursorPositionChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
    {

}
```

However this event handler does not fire if I use Method 2.

What is the best way of doing this while keeping my event handlers in place?

Comment: _Charts.CreateNewChart_ what is that supposed to be or do? A library of your own? You didn't add the new chart to the controls collection: `chart.Parent = chartCC.Parent;` and maybe `chart.BringToTop();`

Comment: Charts.CreateNewChart is a library of my own that creates the new chart that needs to be shown.  I have tested it by generating a new windows form and adding it.  It works fine.  My problem is replacing an existing charts control

Comment: Ok your 'Parent' and 'BringToTop' worked.  The graph is displaying now.  However all of my event handlers (CursorPositionChanged, MouseMove) are not working

Comment: Got the event handlers working.  All I did was to re-add the event handlers:

            this.chartCC.CursorPositionChanged += new System.EventHandler<System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CursorEventArgs>(this.chartCC_CursorPositionChanged);
            this.chartCC.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.chartCC_MouseMove);

Comment: Add this as a solution and I will mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: If `Charts.CreateNewChart` creates a new `Chart` with the given parameters, as one would expect, you still need to add it to the `Controls` collection.

This should do the job:

```
chart.Parent = chartCC.Parent;
```

It is a short hand version of:

```
chartCC.Parent.Controls.Add(chart);
```

which does exactly the same.

To bring it to the front you **may** also need this:

```
chart.BringToTop();
```

Your method 2 goes to great lengths to clone the details of the chart. If needed you will have to do that. But if they all have default values you may not need that. But you still need to add it to a `Controls` collection as above!